# Add item in separated rows in listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

When i add a listview to my form and in form load event i write below code , items added in the same row not in separated rows , how can i add them to separated rows

```
            listView1.MultiSelect = true;
            listView1.CheckBoxes = true;
            listView1.Items.Add("Item 1");
            listView1.Items.Add("Item 22");
            listView1.Items.Add("Item 333");
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

try this out

```
listView1.View = View.List;
```

Comment: You can also do it in the Visual Studio designer by selecting your ListView object and then in the Properties look for the `View` item and set the value for that to `List`.

Comment: @Jinlye I'm just adding this for future readers, but setting it to `List` doesn't seem to work if you're using groups in the list, it still puts them on separate rows as the OP was requesting, but doesn't retain the groupings. I had to set mine to `Details` and add an empty column header to get separate rows while retaining groups.

Answer (score 6):

Taking a stab at this, I'd suggest that it's because your ListView is defaulting to small icons or tiles. Try adding this line anywhere there:

```
listView1.View = View.Details;
```

Comment: I took this approach but then a header appears. to hide the header use the following code:////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
listView1.Columns.Add("someString");
listView1.Columns[0].Width = listView1.Width - 4;
listView1.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
I got that code somewhere on the net once and don't remember where.
Don't know how to create code snippet in a comment, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure ?
Normally, with this code, you should have added 3 items, and you should see 3 rows when the View property of the ListView is set to `Details`

Answer (score 0):

You can try
`listView1.View = View.Tile;`
There is also a vertical sroll bar.